# Mesh does not translate accordingly to WheelCollider

Tags: unity, transformation

So I am trying to implement a car controller script in Unity were the `WheelTransform` position and rotation is set with every update as the same as the `WheelCollider` position and rotation, it all works fine except for one thing: when translating the `WheelTransform`, if the car goes slowly, `WheelTransform` translates as expected, but when the car goes faster, there's a clear offset between the `WheelTransform` position and the actual position of `WheelCollider`. Here's the code were `WheelTransform` position and rotation is set as the same as the `WheelCollider` position and rotation:

```
private void UpdateWheels()
    {
        UpdateWheelPos(frontLeftWheelCollider, frontLeftWheelTransform);
        UpdateWheelPos(frontRightWheelCollider, frontRightWheelTransform);
        UpdateWheelPos(rearLeftWheelCollider, rearLeftWheelTransform);
        UpdateWheelPos(rearRightWheelCollider, rearRightWheelTransform);
    }

    private void UpdateWheelPos(WheelCollider wheelCollider, Transform trans)
    {
        Vector3 pos;
        Quaternion rot;
        wheelCollider.GetWorldPose(out pos, out rot);
        trans.rotation = rot;
        trans.position = pos;
    }
```

Every single one of the car controller scripts I've found and tried use the same code for this section, I have also tried with 2d sprites without any colliders as `WheelTransform` but neither the scripts or changing `WheelTransform` solved the problem. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured the visual objects referenced by the wheel transforms? A screenshot of the offset you're observing could also help us diagnose the cause.

Comment: Are you calling `UpdateWheels()` from an `Update()` function? Try calling it from `LateUpdate()` instead.

Comment: Kevin's solution fixed the issue, thanks

Comment: @user14791290 Great, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of issue can occur if two different components are updating an object's position during the frame Update cycle. In this case, `WheelCollider` might be recalculating the pose during `Update()`.

The specific order that `Update()` is called on scripts is undefined (and should be considered random) unless you've explicitly set a Script Execution Order.

If your script is calling `UpdateWheels()` from an `Update()` function, you would see synchronization issues if your script happens to be updating *before* WheelCollider each update. In other words, your script moves the transform to match the pose, *then* the pose changes, and then the frame is rendered with your transform no longer matching the pose.

One way to fix this is to edit the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html), but I recommend never editing the execution order unless you absolutely have to, because it is a sort of hacky solution (and the UI for changing it in the Unity Editor is atrocious). In this case, you can instead change your script so that `UpdateWheels()` is called from [`LateUpdate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html); that will ensure your code always runs after the WheelCollider has already updated its pose.